# Copying .exe files from ext4 to ntfs

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, ext4

maybe a silly question but..

why cant i copy an .exe file format from linux (ubuntu 14.04) to windows 8.1 without corrupts when i try to execute it?

I can copy some others file formats like images files like .png, .jpeg, .iso, .pdf without problems but why not .exe?

Comment: What makes you think the executable is corrupt? How did you test? Have you made sure that all libraries that it depends on are available on your system? How about registry entries, does it need any?

Answer (score 1):

Create md5 for file and compare  the hash in Windows. Any difference? 
Anyway is the file size different?

Check the permissions in Windows also if anything stopping u from running the file